# login Password recover in android through firebase

Tags: android

How to recover the forgotten password through Firebase?I'm creating an app by suing Firebase and I am getting the problem to recover the password.

Answer (score 6):

Send a password reset email

You can send a password reset email to a user with the sendPasswordResetEmail method. For example:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
String emailAddress = "user@example.com";

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Email sent.");
            }
        }
    });
```

You can customize the email template that is used in Authentication section of the Firebase console, on the Email Templates page. See Email Templates in Firebase Help Center.

You can also send password rest emails from the Firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover a password

1. Via the firebase console
2. By using [this method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/Firebase.html#resetPassword-java.lang.String-com.firebase.client.Firebase.ResultHandler-) in Android